# With an Azure project, when managing multiple service configurations, where are the current configuration choice saved

Tags: azure, post-build-event, azure-worker-roles, azure-compute-emulator

I'm wondering about this because i'd like to find a way to create a post-build event that is different whether I'm trying to compile and run in the emulator or wheter I'm compiling and publishing to the cloud.

I don't know if there is an easier way, but I thought that If I could find where the current setting (cloud or local) is saved I could branch my post-build event based on that

thx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is in a variable `TargetProfile` so you should be able to do something similar to this (which is for after publish, but you get the idea):

```
<Target Name="AfterPublish">
    <ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetProfile)' == 'Cloud'">
        <-- Do you thing here -->
    </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

Comment: Thank you ! (I cannot vote up your answer I don't have enough points)

Comment: In which file do you use these statements? Can i also use it to copy files or directories?

Comment: This is in the project file itself.  Right click on the project -> unload project then you can edit it, it's just an XML file.  When you're done, right click -> reload project.